# WPF Application, Slider is missing Thumb/Thumb.DragCompleted event

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, slider, naudio

I'm following along with a tutorial on how to use a slider in a WPF application. I created a slider. The tutorial tries to tell me what to do when a slider is repositioned so it has a  object [image]

The "Thumb" attribute doesn't show up at all in the intellisense of Visual Studio and note the error when I try to set what sub fires for the Thumb.DragCompleted event: "The attachable property 'DragCompleted' was not found in type Thumb'".

In the PROPERTIES window there isn't anything talking about THUMBS or even the Slider doesn't have the DRAGCOMPLETED event showing up in the list of events when I show the slider's properties.

How do I tell visual studio that I wand the slider's thumb to use an event I've coded for the Thumb.DragCompleted event? I must be completely missing something obvious about THUMBS because I've searched for this error message and found absolutely NOTHING.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't worry about the message, just type `<Slider Thumb.DragCompleted="Slider_DragCompleted"/>` and run. Tell if you are not able to run the code. These are known issues, in some of the cases VS gives you such design time errors. But during runtime these errors dont rise.

Comment: No Luck. The MainWindow.g.i.cs creates this code: #line 16 "..\..\MainWindow.xaml"
            this.sliderPosition.AddHandler(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Thumb.DragCompletedEvent, new System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragCompletedEventHandler(this.SliderPositionOnDragCompleted));

Comment: So I get this error :"No overload for SliderPositionOnDragCompleted' matched deledate DragCompletedEventHandler;

Comment: I guess it's because in the .cs file my event handler sub looks like this: private void SliderPositionOnDragCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Thumb.DragCompletedEvent bla)

Comment: Apparently this isn't what a proper event handler's arguments should be. Honestly, I don't know what it SHOULD be. I can't find any articles on the Internet about it and the example video I was watching had the arguments of the function cut off after "Primitives" so I don't know what that second argument is supposed to look like. Because VS doesn't recognize the Thumb.DragCompleted event, I can't double click on it to have VS automatically generate the function

Comment: NEVERMIND. You were right. I finally found what the proper argument for that second argument should be (private void SliderPositionOnDragCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragCompletedEventArgs e) and ran it.. works fine. It's just really annoying that VS doesn't recognize the Thumb element because I can't have it automatically create the blank function for me and I have to go scrounging around to find out what it's supposed to be. Any ideas as to how I can get VS to recognize this? I've rebooted, cleaned project, etc.